# Candy Crush: How much skill, how much luck?

Tags: puzzle

I'm into the design of puzzle games lately (especially tile-matching games) and was trying to assess Candy Crush's gameplay.

I'm a bit torn on how much success in the game depends on luck and how much on skill. Obviously the whole design is very over the top, with strong emotional reinforcement and feedback for even the most simple actions. But when you strip all that away and look only at the mechanics, I wonder what the true proportion between skill and luck is and how to assess it. I've never found a good, well-argued evaluation of this, let alone empirical data to back it up. All think-pieces on this topic boiled down to opinions. Anybody know more?

Comment: Note that Candy Crush is just one implementation of a more general game commonly referred to as "Match 3". It would really surprise me if nobody thoroughly analyzed that game from a mathematical point of view yet and published some research about it.

Comment: I read somewhere that they used a ML for new levels and adjusted it to get a certain win rate. If it is too low, the level is too hard and vise versa. https://www.infoq.com/articles/candy-crush-QA-AI-saga/

Comment: Following Philipp's suggestion of published research, [I searched Google Scholar for "match-3 game"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=match-3+game) and found quite a few papers. At a glance, many are about training AI to play match-3 games. The evaluation of that AI could include useful metrics to answer your question: the better the AI can learn to play, relative to just making random valid moves, the more room for skill the game must contain. I think reading and synthesizing a few of these papers would make a good answer.

Comment: Do they also force you into a paywall at some point?